# How to save data to JSON server

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6, typescript2.0, json-server

I have a simple angular 6  app where I have buttons  Like and Dislike, I would like to save data to JSON sever (am using as mockup) I don't have API,

Here is what I have  so far

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <p class="col">{{numberOfLikes}}</p>
    <button class="col btn btn-success" (click)="likeButtonClick()">Like</button>
    <button class="col btn btn-danger" (click)="dislikeButtonClick()">Dislike</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Typescript:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'like-box',
  templateUrl: 'like.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './like.component.css' ]
})
export class LikeComponent  {
  numberOfLikes : number = 0;

  likeButtonClick() {
    this.numberOfLikes++;
  }

  dislikeButtonClick() {
    this.numberOfLikes--;
  }
}
```

services.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Status } from '../model/statuses.model';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
   status: Status[];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  statusUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/statuses';

  getStatuses() {
    return this.http.get<Status[]>(this.statusUrl);
  }

  addStatus(){
  }
}
```

JSON:

```
{
  "statuses": [
    {  
       "id": 1,
      "likes": 121,
      "following": 723,
      "followers": 4433
    }
  ],
}
```

Here is the link to stackblitz :[source code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/occ-angular-getting-started-multiple-posts-8nxffw?file=app%2Flike.component.ts)

I know how to grab data from forms using formBuilder, but I am stack now,

I want when user click like button, likes should be saved to the json server and displayed in the front page. right now just displays, because I don't know how to save those likes generated to json

Can some please help?

Comment: If you are looking to just 'store things' for this one browser session, you could store your data in localStorage and later retrieve it, using that as a mock for a backend server. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Have a look at this article https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/create-a-rest-api-with-json-server-36da8680136d

Comment: hii dmc , I dont want to save to local storage I just want to stor in json server those generated likes by cliking like button, some said its not possible  , I need any documentaion to understand this if its true

Comment: @Suryan thanks for link am using the same link  , everything works using forms input , I can add , delete data etc but when It comes to likes generated using button I am not able to create method to save those generated likes and save them to json :(

Comment: Then in that case you just need to add likes property on your object and send it along as you are adding the data as you said and in case of update you just need `patch` to update the likes property

Comment: can you show me how to add that property here I tried different ways I couldnt make it work here is link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/occ-angular-getting-started-multiple-posts-8nxffw?file=app%2Flike.component.ts

Comment: @user9964622 sorry I don't have any idea about json server, I was just telling you the generic way of doing this, and that is how it works...

Comment: thanks bro for helping

Comment: any one please?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a mock server, you need real apis.
Then you can call
`this.http.post(this.statusUrl, newStatusObject)`
To create a new status object on the real server.

EDIT
Using json-server you can do it, but you need to update your json.
Just add an Id field to status:

```
{
  "statuses": [
   {
     "id": 1
     "likes": 121,
     "following": 723,
     "followers": 4433
    }
  ],
}
```

Then you update it this way:

```
  const newLikes = { likes: 122 };
  this.http.patch(this.statusUrl, newLikes). subscribe (...
```

`

Comment: hii , its not possible to just  save data to json via json server and retrieve it ? am able to save data using forms builder but i dont know how to do the with likes generated

Comment: It's not possible as long as you are using an external mock json server. This is the behavior of an API, not a mock.

Comment: is there any documentation about that ? am not able to get documentaion on this situation :(

Comment: That's just another world, another language to learn, another framework and so on. Angular is a frontend thing, so just do frontend, or start learning how to do bakend

Comment: I know backend stafs little bit but I would like to use mock up for now . as documentation suggested to use json server , everything works , I am ble to save and get data as long as I am using forms but am strugling on this likes generarted,  I will try , but am sure there is way of making this work :(

Comment: Okay, I have not understood that you are not using a generic mock server but a specific one that let you add and modify things. At this point you need to setup your json server properly. First of all you need to add an Id field on the status object, then you can call a put or a patch to the endpoint to update the likes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182533/discussion-between-user9964622-and-kaosdev).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`Type s + enter at any time to create a snapshot of the database`

if you pressed **s** then **enter** in the console when the json-server is running it will save you a new file in the same directory as your original db file.

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNqwZ.png)